# ADOBE CQ5 JCR - How to orderby/sorting query builder result using node's property

Tags: java, aem, jcr, crx

basically below is the java coding part, which the result will then be populated to a .csv file. However, I dont seem get the ordering part right (last line in below snippet).

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("path", "/etc/crx-db/form-data/career");
map.put("type", "nt:unstructured");
map.put("p.limit", "-1");
map.put("daterange.property", "created");
map.put("daterange.lowerBound", from);
map.put("daterange.lowerOperation", ">=");
map.put("daterange.upperOperation", "<=");
map.put("daterange.upperBound", to);
map.put("orderby", "created"); //<--here
```

Providing that in crx repositry (**/etc/crx-db/form-data/career**), I have nodes: **data1, data2, data3**...
Then for each node, there is one property - Name: **created** | Type: **Date** | Value:     **2014-01-28T23:21:15.029+08:00** (eg)
However my result in **.csv** is incorrect like (row 1 to 5):

- 2014-01-28T23:21:15.029+08:00
- 2014-01-28T23:48:12.219+08:00
- 2014-02-10T18:44:38.914+08:00 <-- unsorted
- 2014-02-10T18:43:32.426+08:00 <-- unsorted
- 2014-02-10T18:46:53.319+08:00

Pretty sure my code wasn't running. Any idea on how can I tweak my java code to make the sorting happen? As in returning **sorted data1, data2, data3...** based on the property **created**. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there. It can be done as follows.

```
map.put("orderby", "@created"); 
map.put("orderby.sort", "desc"); // in case you want it descending
```

In case you need to check property within a child node, you can provide the relative path to that for the orderby value. For eg., if you are searching for dam:Asset and want to order them based on the jcr:lastModified property of its metadata, then your query would be something similar to this.

```
map.put("path", "/content/dam/geometrixx");
map.put("type", "dam:Asset");
map.put("orderby","@jcr:content/metadata/jcr:lastModified");
```

For further learning refer [this](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html)