# Order of items like in siteadmin

Tags: aem, query-builder

I have a table with a list of some items. The items are the titles of the pages which are displayed in siteadmin. E.g. my items in the table are showed like this

```
A   
C
D
F
G
```

But at siteadmin they are displayed the following way:

```
D
C
G
F
A
```

The task is to keep the order of the items in the table like the order of those in the siteadmin. Going back to the example I want the order of items in the table to be like this:

```
 D
 C
 G
 F
 A
```

Is that possible to do it with the QueryBuilder?

Thanx in advance

Comment: I dont think this is possible using the QueryBuilder, but you can instead get the parent resource and use listChildren(), that returns you the children in the same order as the siteadmin.

Answer (score 0):

By default the pages in site admin are ordered by date of creation. try ordering the result of your query by created date.Check out the link below

[ADOBE CQ5 JCR - How to orderby/sorting query builder result using node's property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676718/adobe-cq5-jcr-how-to-orderby-sorting-query-builder-result-using-nodes-propert)

The order in which the site admin shows the pages can be modified by the user by clicking on the Column headings in site admin.